# How to stop Infinity showing during input

Tags: javascript

I have created a form which works out a sum depending on the users input, this works fine but during the input stage i get the infinity property displayed in the total. Is there anyway of avoiding this?

I'm by no means a Javascript expecrt so any help would be appreciated. Here is the code.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <form id="convert">
        <input type="text" name="child"  onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()"/>
        <input type="text" name="parent" onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()"/>
        <div id="final"></div>
    </form>

    <script>
        function formChanged() {
            var first = document.getElementsByName("child")[0].value;
            var second = document.getElementsByName("parent")[0].value;
            var third = first / second;
            var four = third * 100;
            document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = four+"%";
        }
    </script>
</div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

Comment: Don't divide by zero?

Comment: `if( !second) return;` - abort the function if the denominator is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't divide by zero.

What you want to do when `second` is zero is up to you. But probably the easiest way to handle it is to just not do the calculation and not write anything in `final` unless you have a non-zero value from `second`.

In addition, you might want to check for `NaN` as well. If somebody writes a something in either textbox that is not actually a number, you will end up with `NaN%` in your output. (here you can use `isNaN` or you can compare the results of parsing your values with `NaN`).

So you could do something like:

```
var first = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("child")[0].value);
var second = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("parent")[0].value);
if (first !== NaN && second) {    // note NaN and 0 are both falsy
    // do your calculation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to do some validation on your values first. Your calculation only makes sense with numeric values and you're going to have to ensure that you don't try to calculate it if your second variable == 0.

Comment: Yep, the user will only want to include numeric values as they are trying to find out the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

I think that will work for you.

```
     <div class="wrapper">
        <form id="convert">
           <input type="text" name="child"  onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()"/>
           <input type="text" name="parent" onkeyup="formChanged()" onchange="formChanged()"/>
           <div id="final"></div>
     </form>

     <script>
           function formChanged() {
               var first = document.getElementsByName("child")[0].value;
               var second = document.getElementsByName("parent")[0].value;
               if(second == ""){second=1};
               if(first != "" && second != ""){
                   var third = parseInt(first) / parseInt(second);
                   var four = parseInt(third) * 100;
                   document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = four+"%";
               }
        }
       </script>
   </div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming they only wanted to allow ints and not floating point values.

Comment: Thanks. May be something I am doing but this doesn't return the correct calculation and provides NaN% in the total box whilst the user is inputting.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I wouldn't try to parse/validate the inputs. Do as few as possible, and assume valid inputs. 
Just test wether you get a valid output, before showing the result.

```
function isValidNumber(v){
    //!NaN && !Infinity
    return v===v && v !== Infinity && v !== -Infinity;
}

//cast the inputs to a valid number
function number(v){
    //return +String(v).replace(",", ".");
    return +v;
    //return +v || 0;
}

function formChanged() {
    var first = document.getElementsByName("child")[0].value;
    var second = document.getElementsByName("parent")[0].value;

    var result = 100 * number(first) / number(second);

    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = isValidNumber(result)?
        Math.floor(result) + "%": //I have a valid result
        "";     //values have changed, but sth. went wrong 
}
```